# implementing like system in django and postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

i want to implement a like system for our project,my question is almost about performance,i want to use django with Postgresql DB,in models.py i have a Like model:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name = "like")
    place   = models.ForeignKey(Places,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name = "likedPlace")
```

when a user want to see a post,i should show them if he/she liked the post or not,is postgresql good for this purpose?or any other relational database?if i have 50000 user and each user like 10 post,each time i should iterate 500000 row in worst case.
can i use nosql database like cassendra for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully know what django is doing with this model (I don't use any ORM). But if I understand it correctly it's setting up an association table between Users and Places, where the user indicates they like the Place. If so this can be resolved with a single query and ***NO iterations***. As mentioned I'm unable to write a django model/query for it but I give a SQL to do it, you should be able to translate. The following allows the user to indicate either Like or Dislike, and handles the case where no indication has been made.

```
select case when exists (select like_dislike
                           from user_likes ul  
                          where ul.user_id  = &user_id_in
                            and ul.place_id = &place_id_in
                        )
            then (select like_dislike
                    from user_likes ul  
                   where ul.user_id  = &user_id_in
                     and ul.place_id = &place_id_in
                 )
            else 'Like/Dislike not set' 
        end "Like/Dislike";
```

This could also be easily converted into a Postgres SQL function that returns the same string.

```
create or replace function User_Likes_Fnc( user_id_in  integer
                                         , place_id_in integer
                                         )
  returns text
  language sql
as  $$
select case when exists (select like_dislike
                           from user_likes ul  
                          where ul.user_id = user_id_in
                            and ul.place_id = place_id_in
                        )
            then (select like_dislike
                    from user_likes ul  
                   where ul.user_id = user_id_in
                     and ul.place_id = place_id_in
                 )
            else 'Like/Dislike not set' 
        end "Like/Dislike";
$$;
```

Hope this helps, but whatever you settle on DON'T iterate over 500000 rows when it's absolutely not necessary.

Comment: thank you for you answer,what i mean by **iterate** is database behavior,if the last user that liked a place want to see if he like a that specific place,and i save that like object in 50000th row,database should iterate all other row to find this?or i misunderstood this behavior?do you now how nosql database handle this kind of situation?